An integral containing modified Bessel functions
During my studies I am facing the following problem. Let $I_\nu(x)$ be the modified Bessel function for $\nu\in(0,1/2]$.
I want to compute the following integral (it is are resolvent)
$$
R(z) = \frac{1}{\nu^\nu\Gamma(\nu-1)}\frac{1}{z}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{q'_\nu(x)}{q_\nu(x)q_\nu\left((1-z^{-1})^{\nu}x\right)}dx
$$
where
$$
q_\nu(x) = \sqrt{x}[I_\nu(2\nu x^{\frac{1}{2\nu}})+I_{-\nu}(2\nu x^{\frac{1}{2\nu}})]
$$
Note that this function satisfies the ODE
$$
q''_\nu(x) = x^{\alpha}q_\nu(x) \quad , \quad \nu = \frac{1}{\alpha + 2}
$$
I thought a change of variables might be a good idea so I put $2\nu x^{\frac{1}{2\nu}}=x'$
and get (renaming $x'\to x$)
$$
R(z) = \frac{2^{\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu-1)z}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{g'_\nu(x)}{g_\nu(x)g_\nu\left((1-z^{-1})^{\frac{1}{2}}x\right)}dx
$$
where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a complex number and
$$
g_\nu(x) = x^\nu[I_\nu(x) + I_{-\nu}(x)]\quad .
$$
Eventually what I am interested in is
$$
f(y) = \frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\Im \, R(y-i \epsilon)
$$
where $\Im$ is the imaginary part. My wanna be strategy is to use residues theorem. When analytically continued to the complex plane, the integrand has poles at locations $w_n$ and $w_n(1-z^{-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ where $w_n$ are the complex zeros of $g(w)$ i.e. $g(w_n) = 0$. These are also the zeros of $I_\nu(w) + I_{-\nu} (w)$ and they are not too difficult to compute numerically. Apparently none of them is real (except $w=0$ of course). Also, using the series representation of the modified Bessel function
$$
I_\nu(x) = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k+\nu}}{k!\Gamma(k+\nu+1)}
$$
one can see that it is possible to write
$$
g_\nu(x) = x^{2\nu}r_1(x) + r_2(x)
$$
where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are entire functions of their arguments being power series. Thus $g_\nu(x)$ has a branch point singularity at $x=0$. The cut might be chosen in a smart way to make residues theorem applicable and sum over all singularities.
I would also be interested in a numerically stable method to compute $f(y)$. If one evaluates the limit defining $f$ first it is possible to get another integral of almost the same structure as $R$ but standard Bessel functions $J_\nu(x)$ will appear and these oscillates wildly making numerical integration very hard.
Expanding $R(z)$ around $z=+\infty$ gives access to all the moments of $f(y)$ but giving an analytic expression for the is pretty complicated.
I will look forward an advice from experts in complex analysis for the resolution of this problem. Thank you all.
